# DataTable overwrites previous row

Tags: c#, datatable, overwrite

So I'm trying to add some rows to a `DataTable` but for some reason it seems to overwrite the previous row. How can I prevent this.

What I have so far is this piece of code:

```
DataTable table = new DataTable();

foreach (CallData data in p.ValueArray)
{
    DataRow row = table.NewRow();
    foreach (CallParm parm in data.Parm)
    {
        if (!table.Columns.Contains(parm.Name))
        {
            table.Columns.Add(parm.Name, typeof(string));
        }
        row[parm.Name] = parm.Value;
    }
    table.Rows.Add(row);
}
```

Data example:

```
{
    ValueArray: [
        {
            Parm: [
                {
                    Name: "ID",
                    Value: 1
                },
                {
                    Name: "ID",
                    Value: 2
                },
                {
                    Name: "ID",
                    Value: 4
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Data result

```
"ID": 4
```

wanted result

```
"ID": 1
"ID": 2
"ID": 4
```

I've already checked that it runs through the loops as it should, no problem there. It's when we add the row the problem seems to happen

Comment: If previous row have same  param.Name it is overwriting (row[parm.Name] = parm.Value;). What you want to achieve?You want add all items from ValueArray?

Comment: So in the end you have only one row in your DataTable, but you have multiple items in ValueArray ?

Comment: @mybirthname: That's correct

Comment: @MichaelTotKorsgaard your input object is not correct for your achievement, you need to have 3 "Parm" with 1 "Name,Value" pair to have 3 rows.

Comment: This happening because you have same param names and because of that you are overwriting the value. I wrote you how to do it for your case

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need add all values from Param, not only last. You can try like this

```
 DataTable table = new DataTable();

foreach (CallData data in p.ValueArray)
{
    DataRow row = table.NewRow();
    foreach (CallParm parm in data.Parm)
    {
        if (!table.Columns.Contains(parm.Name))
        {
            table.Columns.Add(parm.Name, typeof(string));
        }
        row[parm.Name] = parm.Value;
        //now you add all items in this loop not only last element.
        table.Rows.Add(row);
    }

}
```